# Cannot display axios data in my PostItem view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I am trying to learn Vue router for vue js ( vue 2), so created a small project following some Youtube tutorial,they are fetching data from firebase but in my case I am fetching data from jsonplaceholder,  and everything seems to work fine until where I want to show specific post with id and its details. Then I am getting error like :
**[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')"**
Any help will be much Appreciated! Thanks in Advance.
My code:
Posts.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Show Posts details</h3>
    <table class="table-data">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="post in postDetails" :key="post.id">
          <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
          <td>
            <router-link :to="`/posts/${post.id}`" class="btn btn-primary"
              >Show Details</router-link
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Posts",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      postDetails: [],
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).then((response) => {
      this.formatPosts(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    formatPosts(postsData) {
      for (let key in postsData) {
        this.postDetails.push({ ...postsData[key], id: key });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.table-data {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-data td,
.table-data th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.table-data tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.table-data tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.table-data th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

// when clicked on Posts the I get all the data as expected from my dummy fake site:
[image]

PostItem.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Post Item Details</h2>
    <div>
      <div>Id: {{ id }}</div>
      <div>Title: {{ post.title }}</div>
      <div>Description: {{ post.body }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "PostItem",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      post: "",
      id: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.id = this.$route.params.id;
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=${this.id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("from Post Item", response.data);
        this.post = response.data[this.id];
        console.log(this.post);
      });
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

// when clicked on the 'Show details' button, it will route me to 'PostItem' page And should show the specific details of that id I have clicked, but instead its giving me error and just showing the correct id but rest of the info/details is missing ( see the image please).
When logging I can see the correct details of that specific item I have clicked in the devtools.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be just a small error when reading the API response.

In your file `PostItem.vue` changing `response.data[this.id];` to `response.data[0];` should work:

```
this.id = this.$route.params.id;
axios
  .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=${this.id}`)
  .then((response) => {
    this.post = response.data[0]; // We are just waiting for a post
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Brian, Its works but when I Clicked on the first Post that has zero index then its gives the same error, " vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:4573 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')"
but the rest post works fine.  Secondly, why I need to have  zero '[0]´ in this line:  this.post = response.data[0]; Can you explain please . Thanks for the help !

Comment: @Ayesha In the case of the post with index 0, it seems to be an api error, since it seems that this post does not exist.
`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=0` returns an empty array

Comment: @Ayesha In the case of `why i need to have zero '[0]'` it's really simple, this api returns an array type response, since in this part you are only waiting to retrieve a post, you only read the first index in the array

Comment: @Ayesha I think it was not entirely clear in the answer, the correction that I marked is for your `PostItem.vue` file that only expects to receive a post, in your `Posts.vue` file where you receive the array with 100 posts it is not necessary make some change 

Comment: Yes in PostItem I only need to see the details of that particular post that I have clicked.
So What do I need to change in Posts.vue file if you can explain more as its not clear for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Ayesha As I said before you don't need to modify your `Posts.vue` file as you have it works correctly

Comment: The error you expose in your question only corresponds to the `PostItem.vue` file

Comment: Yes it's the PostItem.vue where I had the error :) But now with your help its fixed :)

Comment: Hello @Brian, I had one more question that I forgot to ask and it was about router.beforeEach(),
When  use this lines of code :
"" router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  console.log("to which route", to)
  console.log("from which route you are coming", from)
  return true;
}); ""
 ( in my main.js where I have Created router, const router = new VueRouter({....}) ) 
then my pages are empty , the table and PostItem is blank, I dont know what is the issue behind this. Have google but no luck. Any advice or help  from you will be much appreciated!

Comment: @Ayesha I'm not really aware of vue, and it's a bit hard to help here in the comments, I recommend you close this question (which seems to be solved) and make a new one with the question you currently have, so that someone can help you